# What is the Date special property for in Semantic Mediawiki?

Tags: mediawiki, semantic-web, semantic-mediawiki

I am an editor of a wiki that has just installed the Semantic Mediawiki extension, and we've just stumbled on the Date Property. It comes up as a special property when it's used, and I was wondering if there was a particular purpose for it. Would there be any problems in using it as though it was a user-defined property, meaning the "air date" of a video, which is the obvious meaning of the Date on this wiki?

(I have also [asked on the Semantic Mediawiki mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/p/semediawiki/mailman/message/33198478/), by the way.)

EDIT: To be clear, I'm not asking about the Date datatype, but the Date property. If you add `[[Date::12 March 2011]]` to a page, then if you go to `[[Property:Date]]`, it says:

> Date is a predefined property (also known as special property). It is a built-in property that comes with additional administrative privileges but can be used just like any other user-defined property

EDIT: I've also discovered that the other datatypes have similar special properties, such as [Property:URL]].

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: I assume SMW 2.0, as that is the current version, and SMW was installed a few days ago.

Comment: Yep, I just replicated this on 2.0. This looks a lot like a bug, and seems to happen when you use type names as property names. Not an answer, but generally you would want to use more specific names for your properties. `Date` is very unclear; It could be “being a date” or “having some relation to a date”, e.g. ”being founded a date”, “occuring on a date”, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A special property `Date` is not listed on [Special properties](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Special_properties), and it also wasn’t listed there on the [oldest revision](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/w/index.php?title=Help:Special_properties&oldid=16131) containing a table of all special properties. The actual property page [`Property:Date`](https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Property:Date) of semantic-mediawiki.org was deleted (two times), but it still contains the part quoted by OP.

**Update:** As now [answered](http://sourceforge.net/p/semediawiki/mailman/message/33202449/) on the mailing list, this comes from a convention "from the early start of SMW" where "codified" names (like datatype labels) should not be used for property naming.

Their wiki [warns](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:In-text_annotation#Naming_of_properties):

> For technical reasons a property name should not be the same as the name of one of the datatypes.

---

(**EDIT:** OP made clear that it was *not* a confusion of the `Date` datatype, so the following part is not the answer to OP’s question.)

[`Date`](https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Type_Date) is a [datatype](https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:List_of_datatypes).

Every property has a datatype (it’s [`Page`](https://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Type_Page) by default).

The special property [`Has type`](http://semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Special_property_Has_type) is used to assign a datatype to a property.

So if your custom "air date" property should have a date as range, add this on its property page (e.g., on `/wiki/Property:Air_date`):

```
[[Has type::Date]]
```

Comment: I don't think you understand the question, so I've edited it to clarify. I'm asking about the Special Property "Date" (of type "Date"), not the datatype.